# javascript async code runs synchronous, not asynchronous

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, promise

I expect page loading to be finished at `second 2` and at `second 4`, in console.log we should see another text. but the code is synchronous, not asynchronous. so page loading will finish after 4 seconds.

```js
const sleep = (millisecond = 1000) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const date = Date.now();
    while (Date.now() - date < millisecond) {}
    console.log(millisecond + ' sleep finished ' + Date.now());
  });
};

sleep(2000).then();

async function asyncFunc() {
  sleep(2000);
};

asyncFunc().then();
```

Comment: You're using a busy loop to sleep - which is inherently a synchronous operation. If you want to sleep asynchronously, use `setTimeout`.

Comment: A busy while loop will make the UI unresponsive and will cause the JS engine to be stopped by the browser.

Comment: In your code I see some fundamental misunderstandings on basic principles of how JavaScript works. You should probably read some introductional tutorial about js in general and promises and async programming in detail

Comment: I've a gut feeling you believe JS is multi-threaded and async is like spawning another thread, unfortunately not. Your maybe mixing it with something like Rust & tokio with it's spawn_blocking & it's async (futures) / await.